# svn - wrong version for Qt Creator on OS x

Tags: c++, macos, qt, svn, path

In my code I need to display the svn version of my project...

The project was created in Windows and uses svn version 1.8.10

On OS X 910.9) the installed version for svn was 1.7.9 so I had to upgrade it.

I got 1.8.10, and checking from the terminal, it shows that.

I added the installed directory for svn to the path. The "set" command now shows

```
PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/bin:....
```

But.... From Qt Creator, I am still unable to use svn:

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with he working copy at '/path_to_project_folder' (format 31).
You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change

The command '/usr/bin/svn' terminated with exit code 1.
```

So... it seems that Qt Creator (and the command I call from the project file) uses the old path for svn...

The work-around for now is to hard-code the full path to svn in the pro file (the command that gets the version)

But... How can I get Qt to work with the correct svn version without having to hard-code the path in program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Environment section in Qt Creator - which uses its own PATH... doesn't seem to get updated with updates on system PATH but I was able to add to it manually